# How to detect whether MySQL server is running as Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am writing an application wherein I want to detect whether MySQL server is running as Amazon RDS instance?
Can somebody help me out how to detect it?

```
auto_increment_increment1
auto_increment_offset1
autocommitON
automatic_sp_privilegesON
back_log50
basedir/rdsdbbin/mysql-5.1.45.R1/
big_tablesOFF
binlog_cache_size32768
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updatesOFF
binlog_formatMIXED
bulk_insert_buffer_size8388608
character_set_clientutf8
character_set_connectionutf8
character_set_databaselatin1
character_set_filesystembinary
character_set_resultsutf8
character_set_serverlatin1
character_set_systemutf8
character_sets_dir/rdsdbbin/mysql-5.1.45.R1/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connectionutf8_general_ci
collation_databaselatin1_swedish_ci
collation_serverlatin1_swedish_ci
completion_type0
concurrent_insert1
connect_timeout10
datadir/rdsdbdata/db/
date_format%Y-%m-%d
datetime_format%Y-%m-%d%H:%i:%s
default_week_format0
delay_key_writeON
delayed_insert_limit100
delayed_insert_timeout300
delayed_queue_size1000
div_precision_increment4
engine_condition_pushdownON
error_count0
event_schedulerOFF
expire_logs_days0
flushOFF
flush_time0
foreign_key_checksON
ft_boolean_syntax+-><()~*:""&|
ft_max_word_len84
ft_min_word_len4
ft_query_expansion_limit20
ft_stopword_file(built-in)
general_logOFF
general_log_file/rdsdbdata/log/mysql-3306.log
group_concat_max_len1024
have_community_featuresYES
have_compressYES
have_cryptYES
have_csvYES
have_dynamic_loadingYES
have_geometryYES
have_innodbYES
have_ndbclusterNO
have_opensslYES
have_partitioningYES
have_query_cacheYES
have_rtree_keysYES
have_sslYES
have_symlinkYES
hostnameip-10-28-182-30
identity0
ignore_builtin_innodbOFF
init_connect
init_file
init_slave
innodb_adaptive_hash_indexON
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size2097152
innodb_autoextend_increment8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode1
innodb_buffer_pool_size1179648000
innodb_checksumsON
innodb_commit_concurrency0
innodb_concurrency_tickets500
innodb_data_file_pathibdata1:10M:autoextend
```

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA and @Aaron I think only way to detect is to check RDS endpoint name `rds.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT @@version;
```

I believe that Amazon has their own build of  MySQL and  would be apparent there.

**EDIT 2012-05-30**

`@@version` does not return a unique string, but it appears that all RDS instances have the same basedir/datadir/tmpdir, etc, so you could look at `@@basedir` and see if it matches `/rdsdbbin/mysql/`:

```
mysql> select @@basedir;
+------------------+
| @@basedir        |
+------------------+
| /rdsdbbin/mysql/ |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is not 100% definitive, but chances are pretty high that if the basedir is set to something like rdsdbbin, then it's an RDS instance.

Comment: or `SELECT VERSION();` as well. +1 !!!

Comment: @Aaron Brown select version(); does not help either it's same as normal MySQL server unlike percona,MariaDB patches :-(

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Select @@version OR Select version(); does not help as it is same as normal MySQL instance.

Comment: I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER : Never used Amazon RDS

Since `SELECT VERSION();` does not work, here is a suggestion:

Run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` on a standard installation of MySQL and compare it with `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` on a Amazon RDS installation of MySQL.

It is possible that there may be AmazonRDS-specific variables in place.

Try running `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%rds%';` and see if there are any variables. If you find any such variables, then that is your query to run.

Comment: a) only difference is in /datadir/ path and nothing else between Amazon RDS and standard MySQL installation b) also show variables like '%rds%' returns just `old_passrwords` variable name :-(                                                 I have asked to Amazon RDS forums as well lets see what reply I get from them.

Comment: Please run `SHOW VARIABLES;` on the RDS instance and post all the variables.

Comment: I can't post all variables here space limitation :-(

Comment: Please post it in the question body

Comment: Please post all the variables in the question body

Comment: I have edited question and posted all variables there, let me know if you need anything?